# How to sum two columns which already created using sum in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I tried adding two numbers that are present in two different columns but it's not adding up when there are no numbers present in the second column(B). Please find the screenshot of the table and the query I was using to achieve this.

[image]

Not getting the value present in COLUMN A in total sales.

[image]

The query which I ran but wasn't successful.

```
SELECT Date,
       SUM(sales a) as "total_a",
       SUM(sales b) as "total_b",
       ("total_a"+"total_b") as "total_sales"
FROM data_table
GROUP BY Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT Date,
       SUM(sales_a) as "total_a",
       SUM(sales_b) as "total_b",
       COALESCE(SUM(sales_a, 0) + COALESCE(SUM(sales_b, 0)) as "total_sales"
FROM data_table
GROUP BY Date;
```

I do know that Amazon Redshift allows the re-use of table aliases -- contravening the SQL standard.  However, I find it awkward to depend on that functionality; and it can lead to hard-to-find-errors if your column aliases match existing column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse column aliases in the same scope, so your query should error. You need to repeat the `SUM()` expressions.

Then: if one of the sums returns `NULL`, it propagates the the results of the addition. You can use `coalesce()` to avoid that:

```
SELECT Date,
       SUM(sales_a) as total_a,
       SUM(sales_b) as total_b,
       COALESCE(SUM(sales_a), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(sales_b), 0) as total_sales
FROM data_table
GROUP BY Date;
```